# How to get class from HTML stocked in a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm looking for a solution to get class element from HTML stocked in var.

I make an AJAX request that return me HTML content (the 'data' argument of the following get callback).

```
$.get(form_action, form_data, function(data){
```

How could i do something like a .hasClass on data to know if the HTML content contein the '.alert' class?

I tried '$(data).hasClass' and 'data.hasClass', of course not working. Any idea?

Antoine.

Comment: can you post a sample of the `data`? or if it is too big, the first few elements. I suspect your `.active` class is nested inside the top element

Comment: `$(data).find('.yourClass').length`?

Comment: Here the HTML sample. Output when infinite scrolling has no more result.
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
  No data
</div>

Comment: The fool proof method is to add your element inside a new element and `.find()` it : `$('<div>').html(data).find('.alert').length`

Comment: `$(data).hasClass('alert')` works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/7tbn8e9t/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for checking on root level node use:

```
if($($.parseXML(data)).find('.alert').length){ 
  //have element with class alert
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/41cq9vr4/)**

Comment: Though that will fail if the class is on the root element.

Comment: $(data).find('.alert').length return always 0;

Comment: Use second solution as you are looking for class on root node.

Comment: With the second solution i catch " Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: "

Comment: what is the value of data?? the one you mentioned earlier works fine(check the fiddle).

Comment: OOOK! That work fine. Juste the 'true' case that now querying the 'alert' content return the " Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: ".

Comment: how are you alerting them?

Comment: The " Uncaught Error " is throw with this HTML content during XML parsing "<div class="row">



   Name Firstname


  </div>
   <div class="row">



   Name Firstname


  </div>
   <div class="row">



      Name Firstname


  </div>
   <div class="row">



   Name Firstname


  </div>"

Comment: The complete working exemple var data_xml = null;

        try {
         data_xml = $.parseXML(data);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
         data_xml = null;
        }

        if (data_xml != null && typeof(data_xml) != 'undefined' && $(data_xml).find('.alert').length) { /* Do Stuff */ }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66182/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-xabe).